Policy CMP0009 is not set
When I build my package in ROS2 Humble, I receive the following warning:
CMake Warning (dev) at ament_cmake_symlink_install/ament_cmake_symlink_install.cmake:62 (file):
  Policy CMP0009 is not set: FILE GLOB_RECURSE calls should not follow
  symlinks by default. Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0009" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ament_cmake_symlink_install/ament_cmake_symlink_install.cmake:329 (ament_cmake_symlink_install_directory)
  cmake_install.cmake:46 (include)
This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

I've tried using cmake_policy() and changing the cmake_minimum_required version as suggested in the following links:
How to disable policy CMP0045 is not set warnings on Robotics Stack Exchange
How to disable policy CMP0045 is not set warnings on ROS Answers
However, these solutions did not work.
I found that these modules are deprecated in all versions of the current ROS 2 distros, which seems like a good reason to fix this warning as mentioned in this github issue
However, I still have no idea how to suppress this warning.
Does anyone have any suggestions to solve this problem?
